# Can not start rabbitmq on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: rabbitmq, environment-variables, config, broker

I installed rabbitmq using brew install rabbitmq. Then started rabbitmq with brew start rabbitmq. Then I listed services but rabbitmq showed errored status

```
$: brew services list
Name     Status  User      Plist
rabbitmq error   riyad /Users/tecbackup/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist
unbound  stopped
```

then i went to cat /Users/tecbackup/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist. It showed me to configure rabbitmq enviroments.

```
bitmq.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/rabbitmq/sbin/rabbitmq-server</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <!-- need erl in the path -->
      <key>PATH</key>
      <string>/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin</string>
      <!-- specify the path to the rabbitmq-env.conf file -->
      <key>CONF_ENV_FILE</key>
      <string>/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf</string>
    </dict>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/std_error.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/std_out.log</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

i understand that it wants me set the env file but i dont know how to do it properly...
my rabbitmq-env.conf file is ->

```
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq
NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE=/usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq
```

As i am new to rabbitmq, please be kind and give me a proper guide to start and maintain it perfectly...

Comment: are you able to solve this issue?

Comment: yes, i found out that running command "brew update" is very important before installing anything...after that it started smootly

Comment: i am getting error while installing it on m1 machine :(

Comment: use containerized docker for now....it comes in handy for this situations

Comment: i had fixed the issue also posted here as well https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/88128